# Mystery surface behind drwall

Tags: drywall, insulation

Was attempting to install an in wall power kit to hide the wires from my mounted TV and seem to have hit something behind the drywall. Not sure if it's some sort of rigid insulation, but I'm hesitant to keep drilling through it without knowing what it is. It is a tiny bit spongey -- but harder to drill through than the drywall.

Any ideas? Is it safe to continue drilling through in order to finish installing the in wall power kit? The tiles to the left of the hole I drilled is the surround around my gas fireplace.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: The grindings, what are they like? Drywall dust? What do you mean with spongy but harder? Is it like a piece of drywall that's loose but pushes back? If so, could be junk cuttings purposely left in the wall. Be careful when you drill through it, there might be wiring behind it.

Comment: Looks like drywall dust for the most part but didn't try very hard to go through it. If I push on it it depresses a tiny amount but it seems quite solid/hard otherwise. Does not appear to be the same texture/composition as the drywall. Saw somewhere else that it might be soundproofing?

Comment: The disk that's been cut looks like it's ready to come out. Is it still stuck in place? Your hole saw is pretty shallow, has it bottomed out and not yet cut through this secondary layer?

Comment: You could try to cut out a bit more with a 1/4in or 1/2in bit in the center, and see what comes out. Do you have a smaller hole saw? Is it an exterior wall? What's on the other side? To me this does not seem alarming, but caution is warranted. Proceeding with just a pilot hole should be ok for now.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback -- used a 1/4" drill bit and was able to get through it and see there's a stud behind the right 1/3 of the hole, which I imagine is why the hole saw was feeling increased resistance. Not sure what I'll do now but I suppose this is progress!